# saving utf8mb4 strings to mysql

Tags: ruby, unicode, mysql2, emoji

I have a JSON string that has utf8mb4 characters. I first parse the JSON, and then encode the result back to JSON. After that I save the resulting JSON to mysql database. (This is a simplified flow of execution, there is a real-life reason why I first parse JSON and then encode it back).

The problem is that the database ends up with a prefix of the JSON string that I put there and it is cut off right at the first utf8mb4 character.

Here is my code:

```
require 'json'
require 'mysql2'

TABLENAME = 'my_table'

settings = {
  :database => "my_database",
  :host => "localhost",
  :password => "my_password",
  :username => "my_username"
}

@database = Mysql2::Client.new settings
@json = %q({"test":"begin \ud83d\ude04\ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\udc4f\ud83d\udd14 end"})

begin
  obj = JSON.parse @json
rescue JSON::ParserError => e
  @json.force_encoding 'utf-8'
  encoded = @json.valid_encoding? ? @json : @json.encode!('utf-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
  obj = JSON.parse encoded
end

q = "create table if not exists `#{TABLENAME}` (json text not null) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8"
@database.query q

text = @database.escape JSON.generate obj
q = "insert ignore into `#{TABLENAME}` (json) values('#{text}')"
@database.query q

q = "select * from `#{TABLENAME}`"
rs = @database.query q

rs.each {|r|
  p r
}
```

the output is:

```
{"json"=>"{\"test\":\"begin "}
```

I have no idea why this happens, I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Does it work when you use simpler non-ASCII stuff `é` or `µ` rather than emoji?

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for the comment, I did not realise that it has something to do with them being mb4 characters. If I insert \u0428 (Cyrillic Ш) into the string (before the cut off character) then it saves it successfully.

Comment: I had to play around with the `\u` stuff for a bit to spot it. JavaScript seems happy with them, Ruby 1.9.2 not so much. What happens if you don't send anything through the database? Or if you use a binary column type instead of a string type?

Comment: if I use `blob` for the column type, it kind of works, but it comes out as `{"json"=>"{\"test\":\"begin \xD0\xA8 \xF0\x9F\x98\x84\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D\xF0\x9F\x91\x8F\xF0\x9F\x94\x94 end\"}"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to @muistooshort for helping me find a way to fix this:

```
...
settings = {
  ...
  :encoding => 'utf8mb4'
}
...
q = "create table ... default charset=utf8mb4"
...
```

this works only for engines that support utf8mb4 of course.